# How to access static library from the application in qnx660

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, qnx-ifs

I have installed qnx660 in Ubuntu 14.04.

1-I have created a test project hello world for application.In Build variant option i have selected x86 variant. While building the project there is no error message in the console. After building the project in side the work space for x86 its creating both o and o-g folder. But when trying to run project as C/C++ QNX Application some error like "must select a target". So please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

2- I have created two project one for application and second for shared library. From application i want to access API which have to define in the library. But i am not able to write anything because there is no .c file to write. In library project only Makefile and comman.mk is available. So please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project.....then Properties -> Qnx c/c++ project -> Build variants TAB. You must check platform and build variant (release or debug) . Please, see image[image]

then open Debug Dialog and choose Qnx target. Press bug image and choose "Open Debug Dialog"[image]

In the Debug dialog choose Main tab and in the bottom you must choose Qnx Target. I attach screenshot. [image]

For your second question.....simply Right click on your progect , then New->Header File (or Source File) [image]

Comment: Hi Oleg, I have selected build variant and its building without any error. And work space for x86 its creating both o and o-g folder. But when trying to run some error like "must select a target" is coming. S o please help me to resolve the error.

Comment: @DeepakSingh See images. You must choose qnx target.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. In the debug dialog, the main menu below add new target option is there. Its asking host name or IP. But my doubt is i don't have any target board now. So is it possible to run application in the Ubuntu host or its mandatory to provide external target.

Comment: @DeepakSingh In order to run application you must have two machines. One - with Qnx Momentics (your ubuntu machine), second - with installed OS Qnx (Qnx Target). This machines must be in same LAN.

Comment: ok. Thank you so much for replying. I will try to get a Qnx target.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying second question. Now i am able to create header and source file. But how it will get linked to the application. Because i have created separate project for application and library.

Comment: @DeepakSingh See at my first image............ But instead of "Build Variants" you must go to "Linker" tab, in the Category drop-down list choose "Extra libraries" (if name of your library libfoo.a , then write simply "foo") and in the "Extra library paths" point to proper folder..........................................Choose my answer as most helpful ( push at the checkmark under the score of the answer )

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to make it.

Comment: @DeepakSingh `Choose my answer as most helpful ( push at the checkmark under the score of the answer )`.................You know how do it????

Comment: @DeepakSingh When you have upvoted my answer you have pushed "Arrow Up". Moreover you can see "Arrow down"........And just below the "Arrow Down" you can see "V" sign (checkmark). You have to push this sign.

Comment: @DeepakSingh Thanks. I've helped to you and in turn you've helped to me.

Comment: Because of your help i am able to solve my problem.Thank you so much.